# Aggregates and aggregates root how to apply

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I am practicing and trying to implement DDD(Domain driven design)in a project.I am very new to DDD.My requirement is given below.

I have a project.I have multiple candidates for assigning to that project.Project has a client.

I want to identify aggregates and aggregate root. How to design the DDD using aggregates concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can a candidate or a client exist independently of a project?  I'm guessing yes.  Then none of these can be combined into an aggregate.  As you progress further, you'll probably find entities that can only exist within a project - perhaps a schedule.  Then you may have a project aggregate with project as the root.

Comment: @amitabha Aggregates are used to protect invariants. You could consider all of them as aggregate roots until you find some constraints such as "The number of candidates applied to a project can not be greater than the project's max resource cap".